# Recode syntax in R SQL

Tags: r, recode, rsqlite

I am trying to recode variable in R SQL. Below is syntax for the same.

```
Data[,1] <- recode(Data[,1]," 'Yes' = 1; 'No' = 0 " )
```

But when we use single quote in R SQL (') it terminate the R SQL command, in R SQL we had to write R script within two single quotes

Can anyone help me here if I can write recode syntax without single quote in R, or is there any alternate option for R SQL

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for your reply. I tried above syntax but it is not working basically I am trying to execute R script from SQL server where we can write R script between single quotes only

Comment: Would the [sqlserver] tag be more appropriate than the [rsqlite] tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Data[,1] <- ifelse(Data[,1] == 1, "Yes", "No")
```

This uses a different function that doesn't require quotes inside quotes inside quotes. (This assumes that `Data[, 1]` contains numbers and you want to change that to strings.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to check how I can use above suggestion which you have mentioned, but my Data[,1] contains string value so above code is not helping. For Example if I change code to Data[,1] <- ifelse(Data[,1] == Yes, "1", "0") R gives error